# Add attribute selected to multiple select lists

Tags: jquery

I have a page with multiple select lists with the same class.
And one select list with the same value's and options as the other lists.

I would like to change all the selected value's of the lists with the same class by selecting a option in the list with a unique ID.

I'll include a sample HTML code

```
 <select id="selectall">
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 </select> 

<select class="single">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 

<select class="single">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 

<select class="single">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

So i would like if someone for example selects Audi in the selectall class that it dynamically changes the selected value in all the single classes to Audi too

I would really appreciate any help

Comment: You forgot to post the jQuery that you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to the `change` event of the `#selectall` element and then select the other `option` elements based on the selected value using the attribute selector:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/qtkpxrjq/)

```
$('#selectall').on('change', function () {
    $('select.single option[value="' + this.value + '"]').prop('selected', true);
});
```

---

You could also just change the value of each element:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fh1tbkoh/)

```
$('#selectall').on('change', function () {
    $('select.single').val(this.value);
});
```

---

You should use the first method, though, because it's possible that the `select.single` element(s) may not have the same value as the `#selectall` element. See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/egg88o11/) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: OP has already posted the markup and values are same. why are you saying that values might be different?

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I said it's ***possible*** that the values might be different. What's so hard to understand about that? You should program defensively. Since you're here, why'd you have to duplicate my answer by posting the same thing *after* me?

Comment: oh really... you started this game. you posted the second part after i posted it.if you remember correctly....

Answer (score 0):

You can create a change handler for selectAll select. get the current selected value and set the same for rest using `.val()`:

```
 $('#selectall').change(function(){
   $('select.single').val($(this).val());
 });
```

### Working Demo using .val()

You can also set option selected by setting property `selected` :

```
$('#selectall').change( function () {
   $("select.single option[value='" + this.value + "']").prop('selected', true);
});
```

### Working Demo using .prop('selected',true)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#selectall').on('change',function(){
    $('.single').val($(this).val());  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectall">
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 </select> 

<select class="single">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 

<select class="single">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 

<select class="single">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```