# using a single option list for multiple selects

Tags: html, html-select, html-datalist

Inspired by these questions: [Add attribute selected to multiple select lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991036/add-attribute-selected-to-multiple-select-lists) and [HTML Form: Select-Option vs Datalist-Option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865943/html-form-select-option-vs-datalist-option#7002118)

Is there a way to make a datalist non-optional so I could have multiple selects using a single typing of a long list of options?

for example, instead of

```
Tournament 1 winner: <list id="sports tournament 1">
<option value="A1"> Athlete 1</option>
<option value="A2"> Athlete 2</option>
<option value="C1"> Challenger 1</option>
<option value="C2"> Challenger 2</option>
</list>
Tournament 2 winner: <list id="sports tournament 2">
<option value="A1"> Athlete 1</option>
<option value="A2"> Athlete 2</option>
<option value="C1"> Challenger 1</option>
<option value="C2"> Challenger 2</option>
</list>
```

I would like to do

```
Tournament 1 winner: <input id="T1" type="text" list="Athletes">
Tournament 2 winner: <input id="T2" type="text" list="Athletes">
<datalist id="Athletes>
<option value="Athlete 1">
<option value="Athlete 2">
<option value="Challenger 1">
<option value="Challenger 2">
</datalist >
```

Without the ability for a user to enter a custom winner.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for something similar too, but on HTML4 since i might hate to work with older browsers.

The same "solution" i'd thought for my issue (although i've not implemented this) is to use Javacript to set a tag, any tag (perhaps a JSON) and bind the values to the input on click.